# Unable to fix right to left sheet direction in excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

Whenever i am opening a new sheet in excel 2007 it is opening from right side like **F | E | D | C | B | A** how can i fix it like before, **A | B  |  C | D | E | F**. Is there anyone suggest me i have done all my best.

Answer (score 1):

#### Unable to fix right to left sheet direction

Here are the instructions to change it back to Left-to-right:

> 1. "File" > "Options"
> 2. Click "Advanced" in the left pane
> 3. Scroll in the "Display" group to "Default direction"
> 4. Check "Left-to-right"
> 5. Click "OK"
>
>    [image]

Source [How to change the direction of worksheet?](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1763-excel-change-sheet-direction.html)